# Looking for an `is_allocator` Type Trait for Use in `enable_if`

Tags: templates, c++11, template-meta-programming, sfinae, enable-if

Is there a "sufficiently" reliable way to detect an allocator in a template parameter. That is, I need something like a `is_allocator` type trait which can be used in an `enable_if`:

Suppose there is a class template *future* (with template parameter T):

```
    // Default ctor with allocator
    template <class Alloc, class... Args
        class Enable = typename std::enable_if<
            is_allocator<Alloc>::value
            and std::is_constructible<T, Args...>::value
        >::type
    >
    future(const Alloc& a, Args&&... args)
    : _shared_value(std::allocate_shared<T>(a, std::forward<T>(args...))
    {
    }



    // Default ctor (without allocator)
    template <class... Args
        class Enable = typename std::enable_if<
            std::is_constructible<T, Args...>::value
        >::type
    >
    future(Args&&... args)
    : _shared_value(std::make_shared<T>(std::forward<T>(args...))
    {
    }
```

Here, `_shared_value` is a `std::shared_pointer<T>`.

Comment: Have a look at std:;allocator_traits and std::uses_allocator and see if you can come up with something.

Comment: The Standard Library has similar issues, e.g. in [`tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple). It uses a tag type named [`std::allocator_arg_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_arg_t) to disambiguate.

Comment: I don't know, but it seems to be that the allocator type should be known to the class (called `future` here), how are things going to be deallocated without that information? One the allocator is an intrinsic property of the class then is easier because you just need to detect conversion to the allocator type.

Comment: There is a Boost proposal here, https://tickcpp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tick/traits/is_allocator.html . Not sure how serious it is.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such `is_allocator` trait in the Standard Library, but you can write one yourself:

```
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template <class T>
class is_allocator
{
    typedef char yes;
    typedef long no;

    // you can extend this with many more checks on the allocator interface
    template <class C> static yes check( decltype(std::declval<C>().allocate(0)) );

    template <class C> static no  check(...);
public:
    enum { value = sizeof(check<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes) };
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v { 1, 2 };
    using V = decltype(v)::value_type;
    using A = decltype(v)::allocator_type;
    static_assert(!is_allocator<V>::value, "");
    static_assert( is_allocator<A>::value, "");
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3453c86a68f1c20a).

The above code checks whether a type has a member function `allocate(size_type)` by calling that function inside a `decltype()` expression. If such a function exists, the `check<T>(0)` will select that overload in the `enum` expression and the `value` will become `true`. As a check, you can `static_assert` this on the template parameters of a `std::vector`.

Obviously, you could improve this approach by having a bunch of fine-grained traits `has_allocate`, `has_deallocate` and all the other essential member function that make up the entire Allocator requirements in the Standard. Once you have done that, you can define `is_allocator` as the logical and over all these fine-grained traits.

Comment: Thank you very much. This is exactly what I was looking for. I also managed to add a few more checks, e.g. whether there is an encapsulated type `const_pointer`.

Comment: Glad to have been of help!

Comment: @CouchDeveloper Allocators in C++11 are not required to have a `const_pointer` type, [`std::allocator_traits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/allocator_traits) provides a default for `const_pointer` if it's not present. The only required members for a C++11 allocator `A` are type `value_type`, and functions `allocate(std::allocator_traits<A>::size_type)` and `deallocate(std::allocator_traits<A>::pointer, std::allocator_traits<A>::size_type)`.

Comment: Allocators must also support default and copy construction, `operator==` and `operator!=`, and conversion construction from `std::allocator_traits<A>::rebind_alloc<U>` for any type `U`.

Comment: @Casey Thanks for pointing to this. Now reading [Allocator Concepts](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator) for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after getting very helpful answers and comments from @TemplateRex and @Casey, I finally came up with the following *improved* solution:

The helper class template `is_allocator` checks whether the given template argument (the potentially Allocator) has an embedded type `value_type`, whether it implements a member `allocate(n)` and whether it implements `deallocate(ptr, n)`, where `ptr` is of type result_type of `allocate`.

A few requirements are still not checked, as you can see here: [Requirements](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Allocator)

**(Edited)**: applying further improvements after @Casey's comments:

```
template <class T>
struct __has_allocate
{
private:
    template <class U> static std::false_type test(...);
    template <class U> static std::true_type test(decltype(std::declval<U>().allocate(0)));
public:
    enum { value = decltype(test<T>(0))::value };
};


template <class T>
struct __has_value_type
{
private:
    template <class U> static std::false_type test(...);
    template <class U> static std::true_type test(typename U::value_type*);
public:
    enum { value = decltype(test<T>(0))::value };
};


template <class T, bool HasAllocate = has_allocate<T>::value>
struct __has_deallocate
{
private:

    typedef decltype(std::declval<T>().allocate(0)) pointer;

    template <class Alloc, class Pointer>
    static auto
    test(Alloc&& a, Pointer&& p)
    -> decltype(a.deallocate(p,0), std::true_type());

    template <class Alloc, class Pointer>
    static auto
    test(const Alloc& a, Pointer&& p)
    -> std::false_type;

public:
    enum { value = decltype(test<T>(std::declval<T>(), std::declval<pointer>()))::value };
};


template <class T>
struct __has_deallocate<T, false>
{
    enum { value = false };
};




template <class T>
struct is_allocator
{
    enum { value =  __has_value_type<T>::value
                and __has_allocate<T>::value
                and __has_deallocate<T>::value
    };
};



// Test:

static_assert(is_allocator<int>::value == false, "");
static_assert(is_allocator<std::allocator<int>>::value == true, "");
```

Comment: Crazy nitpicking: It's possible that `sizeof(long) == 1`. I would use `true_type` and `false_type` instead of `yes` and `no` and not have to mess with `sizeof`.

Comment: @Casey That's a valid point. I frequently see also `typedef char[2] yes;` and `typedef char no;` or something similar to fix this. Actually, I find `std::true_type` and `std::false_type` better as well. However, then I also need to ensure that the test functions are constexpr.

Comment: @Casey Correction: I could use `struct no {char s[2]; }` and `typedef char yes;` However, I have difficulties to get a const_expression with true_type/false_type

Comment: `static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<T>(0))::value;` [e.g., `__has_allocate`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b3e84defaf79b634).

Comment: @Casey Ah - got this. Improved the traits class according your suggestions  ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a Boost proposal here: https://tickcpp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tick/traits/is_allocator.html

My personal interpretation can be translated into this detection idiom. (Although, as usual with concepts, I don't know if this under/over constraining the concept.)

```
#include<utility> // declval

template<
    class A, 
    class P = typename A::pointer, class S = typename A::size_type,
    typename = decltype( 
        std::declval<A const&>()==A{std::declval<A const&>()},
        std::declval<A&>().deallocate(P{std::declval<A&>().allocate(std::declval<S>())}, std::declval<S>())
    )
>
std::true_type  is_allocator_aux(A const&);
std::false_type is_allocator_aux(...);

template<class A> struct is_allocator : decltype(is_allocator_aux(std::declval<A const&>())){};
```

which can used as this:

```
#include<memory>
#include<vector>
int main(){
    static_assert(is_allocator<std::allocator<double>>{});
    static_assert(not is_allocator<double>{}, "!");
    static_assert(not is_allocator<std::vector<double>>{}, "!");
}
```